# How to deliberately create EXC_BAD_ACCESS in ARC?

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

I got EXC_BAD_ACCESS and I am frustated.

I am using ARC. No more release and stuff. As far as I know, EXC_BAD_ACCESS are not supposed to happen at all!

How can that still happen?

Oh well, okay, if I want that to happen, is there any sample code that will actually make that happens?

Anyone knows?

Comment: try to enable NSZombie to see witch objet causes the crash.

Comment: Set a breakpoint for Objective-C exceptions and then you should have a better idea of where the crash happens. You then have an example.

Comment: Well, no body has a sample?

Answer (score 2):

ARC does not guarantee you program to be free of errors, not even free of bad access exceptions. It's easy to build a bug that **might** cause an EXC_BAD_ACCESS in ARC:

```
void mightOrMightNotCrash()
{
    __unsafe_unretained id a;
    [a self];
}
```

Of course this is a contrived example and the compiler will probably emit a warning but it illustrates that you can create a possible bad access by dereferencing uninitialized memory.

Here's an example that **will** crash:

```
__unsafe_unretained id a = (__bridge __unsafe_unretained id)(void *)1;
[a self];
```

Of course there are other possible reasons of bad access in Objective-C under ARC that don't have to do with message passing or objects at all. The good thing is that they are relatively easy to understand when they happen on your machine: The debugger will tell you where the access happens and what's the state of your program.

Answer (score 1):

From: http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/2011/09/14

```
  // Random data
void *pointers[] = {NULL, NULL, NULL};
void *randomData[] = {"a", "b", pointers, "d", "e", "f"};

// A corrupted/under-retained/re-used piece of memory
struct {void *isa;} corruptObj = {randomData};

// Message an invalid/corrupt object.    
[(__bridge id)&corruptObj class];
```

Comment: An old question but this bit of code works in xcode 8.3 and forces an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  Good bit of code for testing unhandled exceptions.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I have found many time in my project. But it was so difficult to find one for you :)

I tried and found this one :)

```
CFStringRef *str = "anoop"; 
NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

**NOTE:** As you know, ARC is nothing sort of garbage collection or fully error free from accessing released objects. ARC is just a compile time feature where compiler does release and autorelease for you.

In order to get exc_bad_access you can crate any object and let the object release and then you force-access it, it will result into exc_bad_access.